# Is it possible to have a custom view for MFMailComposeViewController?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, messageui

I have a nicely designed mail sending page that I have to implement. I would like to use MFMailComposeViewController to achieve this task but this comes with its own regular view. What are my options? Is there a way to use my own view with MFMailComposeViewController? Or maybe another way to send emails from the app that allow me to customize the view?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You may not change MFMailComposeViewController in any way. Quoth [the documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/MessageUI/Reference/MFMailComposeViewController_class/Reference/Reference.html):

> **Important:** The mail composition interface itself is not customizable and must not be modified by your application.

As far as I know, there is no other built-in way to send email from the device.

Your only other option would be to have the device contact a server of your own which would forward the email message, but then of course the message wouldn't be coming from the email address associated with the device and such.

Comment: Thanks, this does answer my question

Answer (score 0):

Anomie is correct.

We created an app which had used a backend email server to send anonymous emails and we had a custom front end to collect the user message. However if you're just thinking that the composition interface needs a makeover it's really not a good approach and almost certainly will get you slammed during the submission process.

Best Reason for not messing with the interface -

. User will question authenticity of any email interface which does not resemble Apple's email interface.