# Sending E-Mail on iPhone - A Better Approach (plus possible issues..)

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, email, messageui

I have this app which has an e-mail feature.  When the e-mail window appears theres a recipient, subject and template text that asks for a few numbers and a name to be filled in to the gaps.

However I would like to approach this in a slightly better way.  For example I would like a text box and a few drop down boxes in a view with a "Submit" button that, when pressed, would send an e-mail in the same format as above, but the required data would be filled in from the data the user has inputted via the drop-down menu/text box instead of having the user enter the information directly into an e-mail.

First of all, does Apple like this?  I've heard they are not fans of sending e-mail in this way.  (In the background).

Secondly, if Apple would approve of this, how would one go about implementing such a feature?

Thanks,

Jack

Comment: See also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5976507/is-it-possible-to-have-a-custom-view-for-mfmailcomposeviewcontroller

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't speak to the policy issue, but there's no way for you to send a mail from the device (ie from the user's account) yourself without their UI.

If you want to accomplish this, you'll need your own server somewhere that you post the email messages to, and send on the back end from your own email account. This is probably not what you're after, but it would work.

If all you want to do is prepopulate some data in the email message, you can certainly give the user your picker controls, let them set it up, and then pop open the mail composer UI with all the message body pre-cooked. They'll still have to press "Send", but you can own the UI up until that point.

Comment: Ah, I see.  Thanks a lot for the rapid response @quixoto .