# How to hide setToComposer in MFMailComposeViewControllerDelegate?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch, email

This View with the in-app email client shows the name of the individual being emailed. I would like the user to not be able to see who they will be emailing.

```
-(IBAction)email {
    MFMailComposeViewController *composer = [[MFMailComposeViewController alloc] init];
    [composer setMailComposeDelegate:self];
    if ([MFMailComposeViewController canSendMail]) {
        [composer setToRecipients:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"sample@gmail.com", nil]];


        [composer setSubject:@"Subject"];
        [composer setMessageBody:@"message here" isHTML:NO];
        [composer setModalTransitionStyle:UIModalTransitionStyleFlipHorizontal];
        [self presentModalViewController:composer animated:YES];
        [composer release];
    }
    else
        [composer release];
}

-(void)mailComposeController:(MFMailComposeViewController *)controller didFinishWithResult:(MFMailComposeResult)result error:(NSError *)error {
    if (error) {
        UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"error"
                                                        message:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"error %@", [error description]]
                                                       delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"dismiss" otherButtonTitles:nil, nil];
        [alert show];
        [alert release];
        [self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
    }
    else {
        [self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @seppo0010 said, you cannot do that.  Apple created a specific user interface that MFMailComposeViewController uses.  As such, if you use MFMailComposeViewController, you cannot modify what the view looks like.

Your alternative is to use some other message `viewController` that you would have to create yourself.  Create a `viewController` and than transmit the data from the message to your own server or where ever else you want it sent. I tried to create one myself, but I completely underestimated the amount of work it involved.

If you plan on looking for a pre-made solution, I have seem some open source examples that claim to do this, but I've never gotten one to work.

My advice would be to just stick with what Apple provides.

Comment: okay... i think im just going stick with the one apple provided. thanx

Comment: Glad that helped.  Would you mind checking the green check mark next to my answer

Comment: oh. haha sry. im new to Stackoverflow and im not accustom with the protocols. haha  @Andrew

Comment: No worries.  I kept forgetting that when I started using Stackoverflow also.  Welcome to the community

Answer (score 1):

To do that you'd need to code up a custom view with the email sending functionality.

Answer (score 0):

That's not possible. If you intent to use MFMailComposeViewController, the user will be able to see the recipients.

Comment: Then what is my alternative? @seppo0010

Comment: @Brandon: You can send an email from your server as  @ Andrew suggested, but it won't be sent by the user email.

See also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5976507/is-it-possible-to-have-a-custom-view-for-mfmailcomposeviewcontroller